# Send backspace in Javascript to cause normal backspace in Google Chrome shortcut extension (Shortcut Manager)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, keyboard-shortcuts

In google chrome the "backspace" key shortcut that goes back a page really annoys me. So for a while I have been hoping to disable it. I came across:

[Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf)

Which I thought had solved all my problems by allowing me to over write the "backspace" shortcut to blank Javascript.

However it seems to swallow any backspace event. So it actually disables my <kbd>backspace</kbd> key entirely!

I am trying to write the Javascript that would simulate a back space key press but I have never used Javascript before and I am very unfamiliar with executing "snippets" of it.

After looking around I came across this code (on Stack Overflow :-) )

```
  var keyEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
  keyEvent.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 8, 0);
  field.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
```

but this fails stating:

> ShortcutManager: Error in "Backspace Overwrite"
> TypeError: Object # <KeyboardEvent> has no method initKeyEvent

Here is the original question that I got the code from:
[Programmatically sending keys to input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472458/programmatically-sending-keys-to-input-field)

I thought I could skip the button event listener due to the fact the shortcut extension is handling the keypress already.

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

*** Update ***

I changed the code to:

```
  var keyEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
    keyEvent.initKeyboardEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 8, 0);
   document.dispatchEvent(keyEvent)
```

and this doesn't fail but it doesn't work either :(

Comment: I wonder if it keeps swallowing it repeatedly?

Comment: Still haven't figured this out BUT i have another temporary solution, if you use the extension "Hotkeys" you can set "Backspace" to go forward instead of back (so your less likely to accidentally)leave a page). Hotkeys does not seem to swallow the key so you can use it as normal unlike shortcut manager. However you have to set it something, you could choose scroll down or something equally harmless. i went for history forward in case i am playing a game that uses backspace and i dont want to scroll down constantly