# Execute a search on an input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, automated-tests

I'm trying to write a sanity test. Given:

```
<div id="txt-search-wrapper" class="pull-left non-action">
    <span class="search-widget"></span>
    <input type="text" class="search-widget" id="txt-search" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

If I use either of these in the console, the text will be entered in the search box. If I manually click enter in the ui the search will be performed properly.

```
document.getElementById('txt-search').value='test'
$('#txt-search').val('test')
```

However, the following commands will fail to click and perform the search. I've tried to append \r\n to the text but to no avail. I've played around with keypress events too.

```
document.getElementById('txt-search').click()
 $('#txt-search').click()
```

Comment: See the following answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225798/javascript-programmatically-invoking-events http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379949/how-to-invoke-click-event-from-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if I'm misunderstanding your issue, but it looks like there are two separate, but related, issues at play.

**First, .click()**

Your jQuery is valid, but click() needs a handler if you want something to actually happen.

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

[source: http://api.jquery.com/click/]

**Second, HTML Forms**

The input element doesn't actually have ability to perform a search. To do that, you'll need to build a form with a submit button.

See MDN's excellent documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms

For a quick example, something like this:

```
<!-- A common form that includes input tags -->
<form action="getform.php" method="get">
    First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" /><br />
     Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name" /><br />
        E-mail: <input type="email" name="user_email" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Then you can call click on the submit input to run your search.

Hope that helps.