# How to type into input box using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For unit testing, I need to press a key on input box using Javascript so that the input value could be updated.

Here is the example,

After moving cursor to end of input values, and I want to type in number 1 on end of the value using Javascript.

```
// moving cursor to end of value
val inputVal = $target.val(); // current value 1
$target.val('').val(inputVal);

// now the cursor is end of the value

// using Javascript, typing 1 into input box, so that the value should be 11 

// not working, it couldn't update input value
$target[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'1'}))
```

I want to test moving cursor and updating value, so I don't want to update input's value directly,

```
$target.val(11);
```

Is there any way I can simulate pressing a key on input box using Javascript?

For testing I'm using jQuery1.3 which is very old version, so I want to do without jQuery library if I can.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472458/programmatically-sending-keys-to-input-field

Comment: Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225798/javascript-programmatically-invoking-events/1226696#1226696

Comment: `For unit testing,`  For simulating real key presses / mouse events etc, you might want to test your website etc inside something designed for doing this.  Eg.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer  With this you get extra features you don't get in browsers for doing remote control..

Comment: As @Keith suggests, you might be more interested in an external testing framework - another that used to be used a lot was Selenium IDE (firefox addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/ ) but there are other equivalents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using HTML and Javascript as below:

```js
document.getElementById('test').value = 'Test Value';
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Type using Javascript</h3>
  <input type="text" name="test" id="test" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Append exiting value with new value like this -

```
$('[name="aadhar_no"]').val($('[name="aadhar_no"]').val()+'1');
```

Hope this example will help you.

Comment: "*so I don't want to update input's value directly*"

Comment: then what you want exactly ?

Comment: Sorry, but it's right there in the question.  OP doesn't want to use `.val()` as stated and does want to: "*simulate **pressing a key** on input box using Javascript*"

Comment: okay... you are looking for different way instead of val() right?